# How to put ArrayList elements (items) into a TextView?

Tags: android, arrays, xml, string, textview

I have a ArrayList in my strings.xml. I would like to choose elements from it and put it in a .setText(). How do I this?

Comment: you need to let us know what you have tried so far, paste some code of what you have attempted....

Comment: I have the code to set strings in TextView and I have an algorithm that will randomly an element from the array. I know how to do this in Java but I am at a loss of how to take it from an ArrayList in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: XML file saved at res/values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

This application code retrieves a string array:

```
String[] planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Assigning the value to a textView:

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    textView.setText(planets[1]);  //Venus
```

Read more at:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 1):

Should ArrayList be declared in arrays.xml?If so, use `Context.getResource().getStringArray()` to choose elements